# Unable to load native library java; specified module not found

Tags: java, dll

I'm trying to run a piece of sample code to connect to a specific DVR. I've got the SDK from the DVR manufacturer. The code tries to call a native library like this:

```
DHNetSDKLib INSTANCE = (DHNetSDKLib)Native.loadLibrary("dhnetsdk", DHNetSDKLib.class);
```

But, no matter where I put the dll file, I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'dhnetsdk': Specified module could not be found.
```

This being a piece of demo code, I feel this should work. The dll files are placed in the root folder as standard. I've tried copying them to the windows dll folders, gave them a folder of their own (C:\dll), adding this folder to the PATH variable, editing project properties to include the various folders to the build path, pointing to it like this:

```
DHNetSDKLib INSTANCE = (DHNetSDKLib)Native.loadLibrary("C:\\dll\\dhnetsdk.dll", DHNetSDKLib.class);
```

But nothing works. I've searched a lot but I have yet to find a solution. Most threads I come across however usually don't have the module bit in the error. Perhaps there is something wrong with the dll?

I'm trying to do this in java because I want to build an Android application using this dll, but now I'm wondering if that is even possible. The only search results I find are related to native Android code (I think). This project is being run as a standard application for testing purposes however.

Comment: Eliminate any suspected problems with the dll by viewing it in Dependency Viewer.

Comment: Running the Dependency Walker on the DLL reports following things missing:

    API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
    API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
    API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
    API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
    EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
    IESHIMS.DLL

Going to do some more research about these dlls. Seems alot of stuff is missing...

Comment: That'll be your problem! Fix that and the java stuff will work.

Comment: I've found some people with the same problem, and it's because of the Windows 8.1 update. When they asked Microsoft for a solution, this was the answer: "We diagnosed and tried rigorous troubleshooting to find the reason for missing stub dlls on the machine however these are by design on windows 8.1 after the upgrade. We are closing this case as by design". Guess I'll have to install Windows 7 or something to continue developing...

Comment: Exactly the same issue here with the dlls mentioned above. Tested it in Windows 7 and it works. Programming in Windows can be a real pain even when trying to debug...